# What is this part of a bow tie called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, image-identification

What is the part of a bow tie marked in the picture called?

[image: An adjustable strap with a hook-and-bar type of closure. The strap is circular, with something attached to the front side (opposite the closure), but the image has been obfuscated with a big black rectangle, so we can only guess that there's a fake bow tie attached. The strap portion has the obligatory hand-drawn red circle around it.]

Comment: It's known as "cheating".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A pre-tied bow tie refers to a bow tie that is already formed into a fixed bow, and is fastened onto a collar using an adjustable [**neckstrap**.](http://www.swaggerandswoon.com/guides/bow-ties.php)

The (usually metal) bits that link the two ends of the neckstrap together are called the [clasp.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/clasp)